# Change in Proportion - Multiple Periods

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion, group-differences

So I have data consisting of a binomial variable observed in multiple time periods and I want to use a statistical test to determine the existence of a change over time. So here's how it looks:

```
period   number of observations     number of successes    number of fails
1        10                         7                      3
2        30                         22                     8
3        25                         20                     5
4        20                         13                     7
5        4                          2                      2
6        1                          0                      1
7        10                         6                      4
```

Let's say I want to compare period 5-6-7 with 1-2-3-4. If we group 5-6-7 and 1-2-3-4 together and simply use a $p_{1234}$ and $p_{567}$, where $p_{1234}$ is the success rate in periods 1-2-3-4 and $p_{567}$ is that of periods 5-6-7, we can use the usual $ \frac{p_{1234}-p_{567}}{\sqrt{p_{1234567}(1-p_{1234567}(1/n_{1234}+1/n_{567})}}$ formula. However this does not show that $p_5 < p_{1234}, p_6 < p_{1234}, p_7< p_{1234}$ simultaneously. I sense that I must contruct a suitable F-test but I cannot come up with the exact formulation. How can this be done?

Comment: You could just do three one-tailed proportions tests. However, if the decision to test whether there's a change occurring between period 4 and 5 is based on the data, ordinary p-values don't apply.

Comment: @Glen_b Why the p-values don't apply? Three one-tailed proportions can be used, however the significance of all the three conditions holding might be significant while non of the single hypotheses' aren't.

Comment: If the choice of what proportions to compare is based on examining the data, the distribution of the test statistic under the null hypothesis (and hence, the p-value that goes with any given test statistic) is affected by that examination of the data. Hypotheses should be selected before the data is observed, or account must be taken of the examination of the data (in the cases that can be done; failing that we can't necessarily say anything about significance).